# Natural way to express availability

Tags: grammar, expressions, time

I was trying to say this in a sentence:

-I'm only available from Monday to Tuesday 2pm to 4pm. Please come during that time/during those times/in those time window.

But I feel I'm missing something. Which one is the proper way to say it?

I'm looking for a native/natural way to convey this. Context : Someone wants to meet me next week at my place but I'm only available on Monday and Tuesday and at 2pm to 4pm strictly. I would like to tell that person to please come only when I'm available at that specific time window. I had an idea of the sentence like above but I felt like it's inadequate or unnatural especially the <during that time/during those times/in those time window> part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than emphasise that you are not available by using *only*, you could compose the message to concentrate only on the positive aspects - that you are available at some times. Also, try to avoid commanding them in any way by saying *please come ...*.

On of the more neutral and positive ways might therefore be to say "I very much look forward to meeting. I am free 2-4 on both Monday and Tuesday. Either day suits me well, at your own convenience".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized that your approach is better in general. As a side question, if I want to be less courteous and more commanding in a way, what's the right phrase to use if I want to still go with the orginal sentence? <please come during that time/those times/in those time window>?

Comment: Kind of you. Could you perhaps express a bit of regret first? "I regret that I am only free between 2 and 4 on both Monday and Tuesday so please choose which day suits you better."

Comment: Kind of you. Could you perhaps express a bit of regret first? "I regret that I am only free between 2 and 4 on both Monday and Tuesday so please choose which day suits you better."